# wso2 not returning refresh_token in the response

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-api-manager, refresh-token

Below is the token request.

```
    curl -X POST \
  https://172.17.0.1:9443/oauth2/token \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic dXF0c0hnVUp2dnU5X1BDdVEyTjI5dDRqRjA0YTozb1IzYllmN2gxOVBMYmZiTElnR25xNllkQjBh' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: f7ffb7f5-c78d-4931-81e1-a3266da68578' \
  -d grant_type=client_credentials
```

I'm not getting the refresh token in the response

```
{
    "access_token": "867ab2c1-5afa-39f3-a897-5ff4b8a3232b",
    "scope": "am_application_scope default",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 305
}
```

Wso2am version 2.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In client-credentials grant type, the refresh token is not included. It's mentioned in the spec[1] as follows.

A refresh token SHOULD NOT be included.

If you need a refresh token, you should use a different grant type.

[1] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.3